# function with radiobuttons groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

Welcome

I have a problem. I'm trying to build a javascript function that will retrieve me from the selected radiobutton value to div dynamically, after page loads. On the side I have several groups radiobutton. The function is to check which radiobutton is selected, regardless of which group it is and return the value to a div. Additionally, I would like that everyone is not selected range value has been added to the same div.

Answer (score 0):

```
function returnRadio(){
    return $('div :radio:checked'); // you can use class or id to your div
}

returnRadio();
```

Answer (score 0):

To assign the first selected radiobutton to a div, you coud do this:

```
$("#your_div").text( $(":radio:checked:first").val() );
```

As you have many radio button groups, you could have many selected radios at a time. To retrieve them all, you can do this:

```
$(":radio:checked").each(function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers